# Definition of customer-service tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Just saw a question with a [customer-service tag](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/22419/requirements-gathering-form) and it seems to me that the tag is not well-defined. I would expect that tag in a Pro Webmasters setting to relate to serving the "end users" of the website, but in this case it is referring to the "owners" of the website who are themselves "customers" of the web developer asking the question.

Should we encourage a differentiation between website "customers" and web-developer "customers" (a.k.a. "clients") or is there no easy alternative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it matters. The customers are all somebody's customers and so the tag covers both.